# Getting a specific column's value from a ListView filled with GridViews

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm looking for some help with a WPF window I'm writing. I'd like to get the value of a specific column from a pretty cluttered `ListView`. Here is the XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="listViewItem" ClipToBounds="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" Margin="0,0,83,0">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Company Name" Width="150">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Company Address" Width="350">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyAddress}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

`listViewitem.SelectedItem` nor `SelectedItems` have any members that would give me access to those values. Accessing SubItems is also impossible, they don't even show up.

And this is how I do the binding.

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT CompanyName, CompanyAddress FROM Groups", connection);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Groups");
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        listViewItem.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `Binding` for `ItemsSource` instead of doing it in code behind (`Loaded`) and then setting `SelectedItem` with `Binding` to a property on your `ViewModel` all of this will go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cast the `SelectedItem` to your type where the `CompanyName` and `CompanyAddress` properties are defined:

```
var selectedItem = listViewItem.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
if(selectedItem != null)
{
    string name = selectedItem["CompanyName"].ToString();
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think I have defined them anywhere in a separate class that contains them. Where should that be done? I have a helpers class, could I just define a new one called YourClass and add 2 string members CompanyName and CompanyAddress? Don't I have to bind them somewhere?

Comment: How do you set the ItemsSource of the ListView?

Comment: One more question, how would you go about this problem if you had to to with multiple items selection? I tried using selectedItems but to no avail.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.